# How do I get out of the latest version?

Tags: uninstall

This latest version I was offered an upgrade to is AWFUL! Why wasn't any overview provided? I can't find menus for getting to the software I've become used to. Everything is so FUZZY. GET ME OUT OF HERE!!!!!!!!

OK, in plain sober English, how do I uninstall this scary LSD trip and get back to the version I had before?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I'm afraid, apart of re-installing an older version there is no reliable way to downgrade your system.

Answer (score 0):

Scary LSD trip ? hmm...sounds like 13.10...
back up your home directory, wipe the ubuntu partitions and reinstall the version you had before from scratch. There is no faster method.